# Spring Entity Manager with H2 error: NULL not allowed for column "EMPLOYEE_ID" error

Tags: java, spring-boot, entity, entitymanager

I got this error when I tried to insert a value using the POST method in soapUI. Values are inserted in Database when I write insert queries but the POST method does not work in soapUI.

NULL not allowed for column "EMPLOYEE_ID"; SQL statement:

I have both my entity classes here

Employee.java:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="EMPLOYEE")
public class Employee{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=Generation.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="EMPLOYEE_ID", updatable= false, nullable= false)
private long employeeId;

@Column(name="NAME")
private String name;

@Column(name="EMAIL_ID")
private String email;

@OneToMany(cascade=cascadeType.ALL , fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "employee")
private List<Address> address = new ArrayList<Address>();

//Getters and Setters
```

Address.java:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ADDRESS")
public class Address{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=Generation.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="ADDRESS_ID")
private long addressId;

@Column(name="ADDRESS_LINE_1")
private String addressLine1;

@Column(name="CITY")
private String city;

@Column(name="STATE")
private String state;

@Column(name="COUNTRY")
private String country;

@Column(name="PINCODE")
private int pincode;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="EMPLOYEE_ID", nullable = false)
private Employee employee;    

//Getters and Setters
```

I tried to post the below value through soapUI POST method.

{

```
 "name": "Ron",
 "email": "ron@gmail.com",
 "address": [
         {
           "addressLine1": "No 21",
           "city": "Chennai",
           "state": "Tamil Nadu",
           "country": "India",
           "pincode": 187
          },
              {
           "addressLine1": "No 90",
           "city": "Banglore",
           "state": "Karnataka",
           "country": "India",
           "pincode": 187
          }
        ]
}
```

When I try to insert the above, I get the error that NULL not allowed for column "EMPLOYEE_ID"; SQL statement.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the nullable part from the Address entity and then it will work.

Use this.

```
Address.java

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name="EMPLOYEE_ID")
private Employee employee;
```

Comment: This inserts the values of address and employee but, the value of employeeId in the address table is as null is inserted as null. That is the foreign key column of address table.